# VB.Net could not find installable isam oledb excel

Tags: vb.net, oledb, excel-2010

I know this is a question that has been repeated here so many times, but I have tried them all (Nearly) and none help me. This is my Connection String.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\SalikSadruddin\Documents\Working Data\Sharon\01simple.xlsx; Extended Properties="Excel 14.0;HDR=YES"
```

I have tried it with this too:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\SalikSadruddin\Documents\Working Data\Sharon\01simple.xlsx; Extended Properties="Excel 14.0 XML;HDR=YES"
```

and this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source="C:\Users\SalikSadruddin\Documents\Working Data\Sharon\01simple.xlsx"; Extended Properties="Excel 14.0 XML;HDR=YES"
```

But none seem to work and I get the same error

```
could not find installable ISAM
```

Please help we with that, I'm at my wits end. :(

Extra Info:

- Already using x86
- DataSource comes from an OpenFile Dialog
- Access DB engine x86 is installed
- MS Office 2010 x86 is installed
- Using .NET FW 3.5
- Visual Studio 2012 Express
- Using Windows 8 x64

Regards
Salik Sadruddin Merani

Comment: Access Engine could be 64bit (and also Office if installed)

Comment: I installed x86 Version of Access DBE, Office is x86 too but Windows is x64

Answer (score 0):

Could not find installable ISAM.

Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

```
Private Sub btnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    Me.txtstdID.Text = ""
    Me.txtstdName.Text = ""
    Me.txtstdPhnno.Text = ""
    Me.cmbGender.Text = ""
    Me.txtAddress.Text = ""
    Me.txtstdID.Focus()


End Sub
Private Sub RefreshData()
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Open()

    End If
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ' Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter ("select * from student")'

    da.fill(dt)
    con.Close()
    'Me.dgvdata.Datasourece = dt'
End Sub
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into student(stdid,stdName,stdPhoneNumber,stdGender,stdAddress) values('" & Me.txtstdID.Text & "','" & Me.txtstdName.Text & "','" & Me.txtstdPhnno.Text & "','" & Me.cmbGender.Text & "','" & Me.txtAddress.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        RefreshData()

    End If

End Sub



Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    con = New OleDbconnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Datasoure=C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\Student Management Sys.accdb")
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: hmm ... question or answer?

Answer (score -1):

Check with this code:

```
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source =D:\ODD_2015\Counselling.xlsx;extended properties=excel 12.0;"
cn.Open()
```